# JPA Insert Into Large ManyToMany

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have those 2 entities (stores and products) I have the products already and I want to assign it to the store, the problem is that a store could have thousands of products and to make an "insert into" I have to have the products in memory and then save the store with the product set. That makes me have a StackOverflowError and is super inefficient.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
insert into product_store (product_id, store_id) VALUES (:productIds, :storeId)
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stores")
data class Store(@Id
                 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                 val id: Long = 0,
                 @Column
                 val name: String,
                 @Column
                 val street: String,
                 @Column
                 val streetNumber: String,
                 @Column
                 val postalCode: Int,
                 @Column
                 val city: String,
                 @Column
                 val state: String,
                 @Column
                 val latitude: Double,
                 @Column
                 val longitude: Double,
                 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                 @JoinTable(name = "product_store",
                         joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "store_id")],
                         inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "product_id")])
                 val products: Set<Product>

) : DateAudit()
```

Product Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
data class Product(@Id
                   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                   val id: Long = 0,
                   @Column(nullable = false)
                   val codeBar: String,
                   @Column(nullable = false)
                   val name: String,
                   @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
                   val description: String,
                   @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
                   val ingredients: String?,
                   val picture: String,
                   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH])
                   val nutriments: Set<Nutriment>,
                   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
                   @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
                   val brand: Brand,
                   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE])
                   @JoinTable(name = "product_category",
                           joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "product_id")],
                           inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "category_id")])
                   val categories: Set<Category>
) : DateAudit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed like this

```
@Modifying
    @Query("INSERT INTO product_store (product_id, store_id) " +
            "(SELECT p.id, s.id FROM products p, stores s WHERE p.market_id IN (:productMarketIds) AND s.id = :storeId)", nativeQuery = true)
    fun saveProductsToStoreByProductMarketIds(storeId: Long, productMarketIds: Set<String>)
```